# Как закрасить ячейку сетки Canvas по клику мыши?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Ниже небольшой кусочек кода, который рисует сетку **Canvas** . Как мне обратится к ячейке сетки чтоб ее закрасить по клику?

```
DrawGrid=(w, h)=> {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = w;
    ctx.canvas.height = h;
    for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 20) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, h);
        for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 20) {
            ctx.moveTo(0, y);
            ctx.lineTo(w, y);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();

};    
class Draw extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    DrawGrid(600,450);
  }  
  render(){
     return(
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Draw />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

вот ссылка на мой пока что весь код https://codepen.io/xlabuchik/pen/eMpYGp

Comment: На элемент `canvas` нужно установить обработчик события `click` (как это делается - читайте документацию reactjs). Далее в установленный обработчик, при его вызове, в первом аргументе придёт объект `Event`. Он будет содержать координаты указателя в момент клика. Далее найдите клетку по этим координатам

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как найти координаты указателя, а в том как закрасить ячейку по координатам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того что бы закрасить клетку на `canvas` надо использовать функцию `fillRect`

Документация - https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/canvas_fillrect.asp

```
var c = document.getElementById("сanvasId");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; // устанавливаем цвет
ctx.fillRect(100, 120, 40, 40); // рисуем квадрат
```